# Trying to optimize large sql. Have included explain output

Tags: query-optimization

Below is the mysql select statement followed by the explain output.

I have tried adding indexes where I thought was appropriate but with no extra speed.

***There are 2 rows in the 'explain' output that stand out (id 7 and 8 where the rows are over 35,000)***.

I think the sql needs to be restructured but I don't know how to change it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
EXPLAIN     SELECT wo.JobStatusID
       ,wo.JobNo
       ,ql.RackCode
       ,ql.Description
       ,c.CustName
       ,s.ShipDate
       ,s.Qty
       ,pl.PrepLocation
       ,wl.WeldLocation
       ,line.WeldLine
       ,pm.Initials
       ,pqty.ShipTotal
       ,pqty.POTotal
       ,po.POCount
       ,s2.Notes
       ,bm.UnitQty
       ,labour.AssemblyLabour
       ,labour.WeldLabour
       ,labour.TotalGUTLabour + labour.TotalGUTSetUp / pqty.POTotal AS GUTLabour
       ,labour.TotalPrepLabour + labour.TotalPrepSetUp / pqty.POTotal AS PrepLabour
       ,pqty.POTotal
    FROM WorkOrders wo
    JOIN (
           SELECT JobNo
               ,MasterJobNo AS RelevantJobNo
            FROM WorkOrders
            WHERE MasterJobNo != 0
           UNION
           SELECT JobNo
               ,JobNo AS RelevantJobNo
            FROM WorkOrders
            WHERE MasterJobNo = 0
         ) AS r
        ON r.JobNo = wo.JobNo
    LEFT JOIN QuoteLog ql
        ON ql.QuoteID = wo.QuoteID
           AND wo.FOCPlayArea = 0
    LEFT JOIN Customer c
        ON c.CustID = ql.CustID
    LEFT JOIN WOSchedule s
        ON s.JobNo = wo.JobNo
           AND s.ObsoleteInd = 0
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT JobNo
                       ,Notes
                    FROM WOSchedule
                    ORDER BY ShipDate DESC
              ) AS s2
        ON s2.JobNo = wo.JobNo
    LEFT JOIN PrepLocation pl
        ON pl.PrepLocationID = wo.PrepLocationID
    LEFT JOIN WeldLocation wl
        ON wl.WeldLocationID = wo.WeldLocationID
    LEFT JOIN ProgramManager pm
        ON pm.ProgramManagerID = wo.ProgramManagerID
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT JobNo
                       ,SUM(POQty) AS POTotal
                       ,SUM(ShipQty) AS ShipTotal
                    FROM WOOrderDetails wod
                    JOIN WODetailType wodt
                        ON wodt.DetailTypeID = wod.DetailTypeID
                           AND wodt.ReleaseModeID = 1
                           AND wodt.Inactive = 0
                    WHERE wod.ObsoleteInd = 0
                    GROUP BY wod.JobNo
              ) AS pqty
        ON pqty.JobNo = wo.JobNo
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT Jobno
                       ,COUNT(*) AS POCount
                    FROM WOPOs
                    GROUP BY JobNo
              ) AS po
        ON po.JobNo = wo.JobNo
    LEFT JOIN BOMMaterialList bm
        ON bm.JobNo = r.RelevantJobNo
    LEFT JOIN WeldLine line
        ON wo.WeldLineID = line.WeldLineID
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT x.JobNo
                       ,x.BOMDetailID
                       ,SUM(x.TotalPrepLabour) AS TotalPrepLabour
                       ,SUM(x.TotalPrepSetUp) AS TotalPrepSetUp
                       ,SUM(x.TotalGUTLabour) AS TotalGUTLabour
                       ,SUM(x.TotalGUTSetUp) AS TotalGUTSetUp
                       ,SUM(x.WeldLabour * x.WeldEfficiency) AS WeldLabour
                       ,SUM(AssemblyLabour * AssemblyEfficiency * UnitQty) AS AssemblyLabour
                    FROM (
                           SELECT bm.JobNo
                               ,bm.BOMDetailID
                               ,bm.UnitQty
                               ,SUM(bm.UnitQty * pl.HitTime * pl.NoHits * pl.NoMen) AS TotalPrepLabour
                               ,SUM(pl.SetUp) AS TotalPrepSetUp
                               ,SUM(bm.UnitQty * gl.HitTime * gl.NoHits * gl.NoMen) AS TotalGUTLabour
                               ,SUM(gl.SetUp) AS TotalGUTSetUp
                               ,bm.WeldLabour
                               ,bm.WeldEfficiency
                               ,bm.AssemblyLabour
                               ,bm.AssemblyEfficiency
                            FROM BOMMaterialList bm
                            LEFT JOIN BOMPrepLabour pl
                                ON pl.BOMDetailID = bm.BOMDetailID
                            LEFT JOIN BOMGUTLabour gl
                                ON gl.BOMDetailID = bm.BOMDetailID
                            GROUP BY BOMDetailID
                         ) AS x
                    GROUP BY x.JobNo
              ) AS labour
        ON bm.BOMDetailID = labour.BOMDetailID
    WHERE ( wo.JobStatusID = 1
            OR wo.JobStatusID = 2
            OR wo.JobStatusID = 3
          )
    GROUP BY wo.JobNo
    ORDER BY wo.JobStatusID
       ,wl.WeldLocation
       ,line.WeldLine
       ,wo.JobNo;



id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1418    "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   PRIMARY wo  eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_1   PRIMARY 4   r.JobNo 1   "Using where"
1   PRIMARY ql  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.wo.QuoteID 1   
1   PRIMARY c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   sbpdf3_custom014.ql.CustID  1   
1   PRIMARY s   ref PRIMARY,IDX_2   PRIMARY 4   r.JobNo 28  
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2884    
1   PRIMARY pl  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.wo.PrepLocationID  1   
1   PRIMARY wl  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.wo.WeldLocationID  1   
1   PRIMARY pm  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.wo.ProgramManagerID    1   
1   PRIMARY <derived5>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1244    
1   PRIMARY <derived6>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1310    
1   PRIMARY bm  ref IDX1    IDX1    4   r.RelevantJobNo 19  
1   PRIMARY line    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.wo.WeldLineID  1   
1   PRIMARY <derived7>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1102    
7   DERIVED <derived8>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    35736   "Using temporary; Using filesort"
8   DERIVED bm  index   NULL    PRIMARY 4   NULL    35268   
8   DERIVED pl  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.bm.BOMDetailID 1   
8   DERIVED gl  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   sbpdf3_custom014.bm.BOMDetailID 1   
6   DERIVED WOPOs   index   NULL    IDX_1   4   NULL    1804    "Using index"
5   DERIVED wod ref IDX_1   IDX_1   1       1660    "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
5   DERIVED wodt    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   sbpdf3_custom014.wod.DetailTypeID   1   "Using where"
4   DERIVED WOSchedule  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2884    "Using filesort"
2   DERIVED WorkOrders  range   IDX_2   IDX_2   4   NULL    15  "Using where; Using index"
3   UNION   WorkOrders  ref IDX_2   IDX_2   4       689 "Using index"
NULL    "UNION RESULT"  <union2,3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot to look through here, but I did spot this subquery:

```
  SELECT JobNo
       ,MasterJobNo AS RelevantJobNo
    FROM WorkOrders
    WHERE MasterJobNo != 0
   UNION
   SELECT JobNo
       ,JobNo AS RelevantJobNo
    FROM WorkOrders
    WHERE MasterJobNo = 0
```

which I believe could be re-written like so:

```
      SELECT JobNo
           ,CASE WHEN MasterJobNo != 0 
                THEN MasterJobNo 
                ELSE JobNo END AS RelevantJobNo
       FROM WorkOrders
```

And once we re-write it this way, we wonder why it needs to be a subquery, rather than simply joining to the table. And then I look again and see that we've already used this table in the query, and so we can eliminate that join entirely, and just include the CASE expression in the appropriate places.  Moreover, this expression is only used in one place that I could spot (the join to BOMMaterialList).

I also noticed this subquery:

```
SELECT JobNo
       ,Notes
FROM WOSchedule
ORDER BY ShipDate DESC
```

I think we can eliminate this, as well. ORDER BY without a LIMIT has no meaning here when used as a derived table, and again: this table is already included in the query in another place. The only difference between the data provided this `s2` subquery and the prior `s` table is the check on the ObsoleteInd field, and the only place data from `s2` is used elsewhere is the `Notes` field in the select clause. The `s` table is only used in select list of the ShipDate and Qty items.

So I can get us down to this, which should show some improvement:

```
SELECT wo.JobStatusID
   ,wo.JobNo
   ,ql.RackCode
   ,ql.Description
   ,c.CustName
   ,case when s.ObsoleteInd = 0 then s.ShipDate else null end as ShipDate
   ,case when s.ObsoleteInd = 0 then s.Qty else null end as Qty
   ,pl.PrepLocation
   ,wl.WeldLocation
   ,line.WeldLine
   ,pm.Initials
   ,pqty.ShipTotal
   ,pqty.POTotal
   ,po.POCount
   ,s.Notes
   ,bm.UnitQty
   ,labour.AssemblyLabour
   ,labour.WeldLabour
   ,labour.TotalGUTLabour + labour.TotalGUTSetUp / pqty.POTotal AS GUTLabour
   ,labour.TotalPrepLabour + labour.TotalPrepSetUp / pqty.POTotal AS PrepLabour
   ,pqty.POTotal
FROM WorkOrders wo
 LEFT JOIN QuoteLog ql
    ON ql.QuoteID = wo.QuoteID
       AND wo.FOCPlayArea = 0
LEFT JOIN Customer c
    ON c.CustID = ql.CustID
LEFT JOIN WOSchedule s
    ON s.JobNo = wo.JobNo
LEFT JOIN PrepLocation pl
    ON pl.PrepLocationID = wo.PrepLocationID
LEFT JOIN WeldLocation wl
    ON wl.WeldLocationID = wo.WeldLocationID
LEFT JOIN ProgramManager pm
    ON pm.ProgramManagerID = wo.ProgramManagerID
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT JobNo
                   ,SUM(POQty) AS POTotal
                   ,SUM(ShipQty) AS ShipTotal
                FROM WOOrderDetails wod
                JOIN WODetailType wodt
                    ON wodt.DetailTypeID = wod.DetailTypeID
                       AND wodt.ReleaseModeID = 1
                       AND wodt.Inactive = 0
                WHERE wod.ObsoleteInd = 0
                GROUP BY wod.JobNo
          ) AS pqty
    ON pqty.JobNo = wo.JobNo
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Jobno
                   ,COUNT(*) AS POCount
                FROM WOPOs
                GROUP BY JobNo
          ) AS po
    ON po.JobNo = wo.JobNo
LEFT JOIN BOMMaterialList bm
    ON bm.JobNo = CASE WHEN wo.MasterJobNo != 0 THEN wo.MasterJobNo ELSE wo.JobNo END
LEFT JOIN WeldLine line
    ON wo.WeldLineID = line.WeldLineID
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT x.JobNo
                   ,x.BOMDetailID
                   ,SUM(x.TotalPrepLabour) AS TotalPrepLabour
                   ,SUM(x.TotalPrepSetUp) AS TotalPrepSetUp
                   ,SUM(x.TotalGUTLabour) AS TotalGUTLabour
                   ,SUM(x.TotalGUTSetUp) AS TotalGUTSetUp
                   ,SUM(x.WeldLabour * x.WeldEfficiency) AS WeldLabour
                   ,SUM(AssemblyLabour * AssemblyEfficiency * UnitQty) AS AssemblyLabour
                FROM (
                       SELECT bm.JobNo
                           ,bm.BOMDetailID
                           ,bm.UnitQty
                           ,SUM(bm.UnitQty * pl.HitTime * pl.NoHits * pl.NoMen) AS TotalPrepLabour
                           ,SUM(pl.SetUp) AS TotalPrepSetUp
                           ,SUM(bm.UnitQty * gl.HitTime * gl.NoHits * gl.NoMen) AS TotalGUTLabour
                           ,SUM(gl.SetUp) AS TotalGUTSetUp
                           ,bm.WeldLabour
                           ,bm.WeldEfficiency
                           ,bm.AssemblyLabour
                           ,bm.AssemblyEfficiency
                        FROM BOMMaterialList bm
                        LEFT JOIN BOMPrepLabour pl
                            ON pl.BOMDetailID = bm.BOMDetailID
                        LEFT JOIN BOMGUTLabour gl
                            ON gl.BOMDetailID = bm.BOMDetailID
                        GROUP BY BOMDetailID
                     ) AS x
                GROUP BY x.JobNo
          ) AS labour
    ON bm.BOMDetailID = labour.BOMDetailID
WHERE ( wo.JobStatusID = 1
        OR wo.JobStatusID = 2
        OR wo.JobStatusID = 3
      )
GROUP BY wo.JobNo
ORDER BY wo.JobStatusID
   ,wl.WeldLocation
   ,line.WeldLine
   ,wo.JobNo;
```

There are likely a few other improvements like this possible, but I suspect most improvement will come from examining your index use.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I needed. Great explanation. This reduced the sql time by 90%. Thank you so much.

Comment: Curious: what were rough starting and ending run times?

Comment: Just over 4 minutes down to just under 30 seconds